# UDP using ethernet cable point to point communication is not working?

Tags: python, windows, sockets, udp

I have connected two windows machines using ethernet cable and i assigned static ip for each computer. I used wireshark on both machines to monitor the packets. I have used python socket to send UDP packets.

sender.py

```
import socket
import time

DST_IP="192.168.0.191"
DST_PORT=2000

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP

message = b"your very important message"
while True:
    sock.sendto(message, (DST_IP,DST_PORT))
    print("message sent!")
    time.sleep(1)
```

receiver.py

```
import socket
import time

UDP_IP = "192.168.0.191"
UDP_PORT = 2000


sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP

sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))


while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    print(data)
```

sender computer have address 192.168.0.155 and receiver has 192.168.1.191 wireshark shark on sender shows packet is sent and wireshark on receiver shows the packet is received. 
But receiver side python doesn't show anything.

Why python socket is not receving anything whereas wireshark does?

Comment: Because Windows Firewall.  Open up a port exception and/or for Python.exe.  Also, I'm assuming you have validated both PCs can reach each other with some other application. Not sure what your network mask is, but if it's `255.255.255.0`, then you've got two machines not the same subnet.  Consider changing both IPs be to on the 192.168.1.*` range

Comment: Also, just as a good thing, don't bind to a specific IP address.  Bind to "0.0.0.0" on the receive side so your socket is open on all networks.

Comment: But sending the packet in opposite direction receives the data. Means from computer2 to computer1 works.

Comment: @selbie I can see the packets on wireshark software on both the machines. Sending data from 192.168.0.155 to 192.168.0.191 not works But from 192.168.0.191 to 192.168.0.155 works. Subnet mask is 255.255.255.0

Comment: It's probably the firewall.  Turn off Windows firewall on both machines and see what happens.

Comment: @selbie Its worked! Thanks. How can i do this without turning off the firewall?

Comment: Register python.exe as a firewall exception for inbound.